# How to load critical styles for a NextJs app

Tags: css, webpack, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-rewrites

I have played around with the experimental feature `optimizeCss`, but [vercel suggests that we don't use it anymore](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53863#issuecomment-1699374242). Also, I am not really sure how this would work when we try Server side streaming.

I have also tried exploring the NextJs [Middleware util](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware) to check if there is a way for me to access the html but I hit a dead-end.

What is the right way to access the baked html before it is sent out so that I can try and also pack the critical css as required?

[A similar question was already posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969554/correct-way-to-setup-critical-css-for-nextjs-project-and-remove-unwanted-css) but, I think looking at the raw html, we will be able to better determine the required css than what [Purgecss](https://purgecss.com/) does.