# Is there a possibility of converting react css modules to inline css on production

Tags: webpack, sass, next.js, server-side-rendering, css-in-js

This may be an unusual question. I want to explore the possibility of converting CSS/SCSS files into inline with HTML on production mode.

```
import styles from "./index.module.scss";

function Welcome(props) {
 return <h1 className={styles.title}>Hello, Doe</h1>;
}
```

==== **This will result something like this** ======

```
  <html>
    <Head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/style.css" />
    </Head>
    <body>
      <h1 className="style_title3dwe">Hello, Doe</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
```

==== **What i expect have on production is** ======

```
 <html>
    <Head>
      <style>
         .style_title3dwe { font-size: var(--fs1); }
      </style>
    </Head>
    <body>
      <h1 className="style_title3dwe">Hello, Doe</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: How do you configure Webpack?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: nope, not yet. I did not found a solution. I'm considered another approach when i have time.

Comment: See related question: [How to inline CSS in the head tag of a NextJS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057947/how-to-inline-css-in-the-head-tag-of-a-nextjs-project).

Answer (score 0):

[style-loader documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/) may help you

You can pass the `injectType` you need:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          // The `injectType`  option can be avoided because it is default behaviour
          { loader: "style-loader", options: { injectType: "styleTag" } },
          "css-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

`injectType` can be one of the following values::

```js
type injectType =
  | "styleTag"
  | "singletonStyleTag"
  | "autoStyleTag"
  | "lazyStyleTag"
  | "lazySingletonStyleTag"
  | "lazyAutoStyleTag"
  | "linkTag";
```

P.S. In my current environment without setting up the `style-loader`, it works exactly as you described - added `<style>` tags inside `<head>`
[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hooks-gz1dvu)