# How to apply styles to the HTML in Next.js at server side render?

Tags: html, css, next.js, server-side-rendering, critical-css

Visit [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) and notice the page request in the network tab. Preview shows not just the HTML but completely pre-styled page.

[image]

When we use `Styled-Components` and `Material-UI` they have exposed `ServerStyleSheet` which is used for serving the required styles for the first render within the HTML.

```
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
```

How can we achieve same output when using `react-bootstrap` or custom css like `test.css`?

Answer (score 2):

Do you care if its a test.css or React bootstrap - Instead why not just inline all critical stylesheets?

It might be worth trying out their experimental feature

> 1. Add `experimental: { optimizeCss: true }` to next.config.js
> 2. Install critters@0.0.7 as a dependency

Via [How to inline CSS in the head tag of a NextJS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057947/how-to-inline-css-in-the-head-tag-of-a-nextjs-project)

Answer (score 0):

Add your style file on the the _app file, you can create this file inside the pages directory in nextjs

```
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "../your_style.css";

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}


export default App;
```

for react-bootstrap , you need to add `npm i react-bootstrap bootstrap`

Answer (score 0):

> Nextjs allows you to display SSG/SSR pages and javascript-disabled
> users will still be able to see your app but the layout will be messy
> if you use react-bootstrap components to build your layout.

**To use react-bootstrap at SSR:**

1. Install :

   ```
   npm i react-bootstrap bootstrap
   ```
2. Import bootstrap styles in your `_app.js`:

   ```
   import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
   ```
3. You can then use your `react-bootstrap components` as you would do in reactjs:

```
import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
        
const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <p>Running on Next.js at SSR</p>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  </>
);
        
export default Layout;
```

Answer (score -1):

use Tailwind css

https://tailwindcss.com/

We can simply use classes and it make everything super easy for you design

Comment: Hey Adarsh! While Tailwind is a great and useful tool, it doesn't actually solve his question. They want to know how they can achieve that with `react-bootstrap` or other styles.

Comment: Also I think you are wrong, tailwindcss doesn't work if JS is disabled (styles are not part of the HTML file).