# Why is a statically generated page unstyled when sent to the client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When running the Next.js official boilerplate `npx create-next-app` and previewing it in the browser, I noticed the statically generated html document isn't styled:

[image]

I believe this could lead to [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) problems. How can I make sure that the page is already styled when served to the client, as in the case of [Next.js' official site](https://nextjs.org/):

[image]

Note: I just created a boilerplate project using `npx create-next-app` and did not modify any code. I am using Next.js v12.0.7 and React v17.0.2.

Comment: Perhaps you use something like this: https://github.com/t09tanaka/next-critical

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to inline CSS in the head tag of a NextJS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057947/how-to-inline-css-in-the-head-tag-of-a-nextjs-project)? You need to inline the CSS for that to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the response similar to Next.js' website, you need to inline critical CSS. This is (still) experimental in `next@12.0.7` (and undocumented). To enable it modify your `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  experimental: { optimizeCss: true }
}
```

You need to install `critters` (`yarn add -D critters` or `npm i -D critters`) for this to work. Also, you need to run production build (`next build && next start`) not a dev one like you're doing in that image you have shared.

**Result:**

[image]